# lower bound on 2-norm

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis

Is there a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^n\to(0,\infty)$ such that for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$,
\begin{align}
-(x^{\rm T}y)^2\leq-f(x,y)\|x\|_2^2.
\end{align}

Comment: Please refrain from completely changing a question, as this creates confusion and invalidates all the answers that were given so far. If you have a new question, you should open a new thread. You should probably start the new thread with your actual problem, as such a function doesn't exist. You probably want to prove something completely different and have taken a wrong turn at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such function. Your inequality is equivalent to

$$f(x, y) \|x\|_2^2 \le (x^ty)^2,$$

but this inequality can't be satisfied for $y = 0$ and $x \ne 0$, unless $f(x, 0) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks. How about this: Is there a non-zero function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^n\to[0,\infty)$ such that for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$,
\begin{align}
-(x^{\rm T}y)^2\leq-f(x,y)\|x\|_2^2.
\end{align}

Comment: Sure, just take $f(x, y) = (x^ty)^2\|x\|_2^{-2}$ for $x \ne 0$ and let it assume an arbitrary value when $x = 0$.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know exactly how to ask it rigorously. I need a function which is not explicitly dependent on ($x^{\rm T}y$)

Comment: Then open a new question with the original problem. This guessing what you want leads to nowhere. Usually such problems arise in other questions and are not really necessary.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

What happens if $x^Ty=0$ for $x\ne 0$?